# What is Wrong with my Django logging configuration? No logs are seen in the log file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, logging, django-logging

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'server_logger': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*100,
            'backupCount': 20,
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'server.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['server_logger'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

What is wrong with the above configuration and why don't I see my logs? Any thoughts?

Comment: 1. Print out BASE_DIR and make sure it's what you expect. It should preferably be an absolute path. 2. Does anything change if you change `'django'` to `''` under `'loggers'`?

Comment: Alex, the second suggestion has worked. Do you want to comment, I will accept the answer? Also, could you explain why? 'django' means only for modules that start with 'django' and '' means for everything?

Comment: That's roughly it. Do you want this logger to capture everything, or were you hoping to get only django logs?

Comment: I wanted it to capture everything. Thanks, Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the empty string `''` as the key under `'loggers'` to mark that as the root logger and capture messages from all loggers.